# My React Shopping Cart code block is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

When I click on the add to cart button, the first item is added to the cart, but when I click on the same item again, its quantity should be updated, not the whole item. Does anyone, please help me I am confused know what to do

```
 const addtoCart = (e,newData) => {
//console.log("hello",newData)
//setAddCart(newData)
//console.log("Test",dataStore)
const dataStore = newData
const Item = addcart.find(a => { return a.API === dataStore})
console.log("A",Item)
console.log("Before",dataStore)
if(Item === undefined){
  dataStore.quantity = 1;
  setAddCart(prev => [...prev,dataStore])
  console.log("AfterinIf",dataStore)
}
else{
  Item.quantity = + 1;
  const CartUpdate  = addcart.filter(a => { return a.API !== Item.API});
  CartUpdate.push(Item);  
  setAddCart(CartUpdate);
  console.log("Update",CartUpdate)
}


  
}
```

Comment: When you debug, what specifically happens in this code?  Following each operation being performed, which one first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used at the time?  What was the result observed?  What was expected?  Why?

Comment: Are you sure `const Item = addcart.find(a => { return a.API === dataStore})` is returning the correct item after you click for the second time? Maybe your `a.API === dataStore` check is not working as expected.

Comment: @HassanKhalid yes my a.API === dataStore is not storing value every time i click it shows undefined and if statement gets run not else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
Item.quantity = + 1;
```

to

```
Item.quantity = Item.quantity + 1;
```

Comment: or `+= 1` or `++` :p